# Для какой цели используют такой синтаксис?

Tags: perl

```
use lib '/full/path/to';
require 'script.pl';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[use lib "simplifies the manipulation of @INC at compile time."](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html), в частности, в данном случае, добавляет /full/path/to к `@INC` (список путей, в которых ищутся библиотеки). Поэтому в дальнейшем, чтобы подключить /full/path/to/script.pl, достаточно указать только имя script.pl, без полного пути.

[require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) — директива, среди прочего, и для подключения библиотек без импорта их символов.