# Как подключить модуль в Perl, который не прописан в @INC?

Tags: perl

При условии, что скрипт и модуль находятся в одной директории, и без указания пути к модулю.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для какой цели используют такой синтаксис?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833139/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# стандартные библиотеки
use ...; 
use ...;
use ...;

#указываем новую папку с вашими библиотеками
use lib "../"; 
use MYMODULE;
```

Comment: указывается только относительный путь каталога к самому себе

Comment: @usr13 да, без указания пути. Вы пишете ``use lib '/home/vasya/perl-project';`` в котором у вас лежит модуль ``Module.PM``, и следующей строкой его подключаете - ``use Module.PM;``

Comment: да, все работает, благодарю, немного поправить только:  use lib "./";